# GCP Counter log metrics as a barchart

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have cloud run endpoint that generates some logs.

I want to display the number of time those differents logs have been triggered per day in a bar chart.
To do this, I filtered my logs with the right criteria, created a counter metric and then used the monitoring metrics explorer to create a bar chart.

It kind of work but the numbers it shows are quite different from what I can count in the logs if I do it manually. Do you have some pointer on what I could be doing wrong ?

Is there something I do wrong in the configuration :
[image]

Thank you !

Comment: There could be many reasons why there is gap between logs; Please confirm you are using the same time range and moreover monitoring metrics are aggregating the number of logs as a single event for a certain time period and you may be counting each log as a separate event.

Comment: About the time range, I'm pretty sure I'm comparing the same thing.
But, I'm not sure I'm aggregating the number of logs correctly. How can I check that ? Is there a way to debug it ?

Comment: Goro Monitoring page for your project->click Metrics Explorer->Find resource type and metric and enter your counter metric->filter and select log based metric which you want to view->Under time Group by select the timer interval and Preview it.

Comment: above method is to counter check;

Comment: To check aggregation settings go to the chart settings in the monitoring metrics explorer and look for the Aggregation section.  You can manually download them in CSV file as well to analyze. But, as far as I know you are getting the problem with the time interval. Any difference in the locations?